# Find out when user followed an account - rtweet

Tags: r, twitter, social-networking

I'm curious to see when accounts started following me on Twitter (and when I started following accounts). It'd be interesting to see my user activity related to the types of accounts I follow, as well as maps of my followers/followings over time + season.

I've tried *getting followers* and *lookup users* in the following manner:

```
followers <- get_followers("twitterhandlehere", n = 50)
followers_data <- lookup_users(followers$user_id)
```

**Followers_data** is a data frame with user info including profile picture, bio, and when the user's account was created, but no where in there does it indicate when the relationship started, as far as I can tell.

Nor does this function seem to indicate the date in which the follow/following started:

```
lookup_friendship("BarackObama", "MyUsername")
```

It appears the API didn't support this functionality in the past, and I understand I can stream this data in the future - but is there any way to salvage specificity in the past data?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not available in the API. You would have to have been regularly polling the friends and followers endpoints to record those changes. You cannot discover it from the API at a specific point in time, you'd have to make the record of follower list changes youself.